# как работает laravel page cache

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel создает cache каждого запроса, как он потом определяет 
`были ли изменения в базе` 
допустим и выводит ответ из cache если не было изменений или создает новый cache если были изменения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты о кешировании views, то посмотри в storage/framework/views. Там сохраняются обработанный blade в "голый" php.

Если ты хочешь что нибудь закешировать, ты сам указываешь время кеширования, по истечению которого кеш будет обновлён. Ты так же можешь закешировать навечно. В таком случае для обновления тебе достаточно

```
Cache::forget('key');
```

После чего кеш будет обновлён по первой необходимости автоматически.

[Документация по cache laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache)

Comment: Если нужно закешировать весь HTML, используй возможности своего веб сервера.